# Unexpected amount of lines when writing to a csv file

Tags: java, csv, bufferedwriter, byte-order-mark

A part of my application writes data to a .csv file in the following way:

```
public class ExampleWriter {

    public static final int COUNT = 10_000;
    public static final String FILE = "test.csv";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try (OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(FILE)){         
            os.write(239);
            os.write(187);
            os.write(191);
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));         
            for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++) {               
                writer.write(Integer.toString(i));
                writer.newLine();               
            }           
        } catch (IOException e) {                       
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println(checkLineCount(COUNT, new File(FILE)));
    }

    public static String checkLineCount(int expectedLineCount, File file) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader expectedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        try {
            int lineCount = 0;
            while (expectedReader.readLine() != null) {
                lineCount++;
            }
            if (expectedLineCount == lineCount) {
                return "correct";       
            } else {
                return "incorrect"; 
            }
        }
        finally {
            expectedReader.close();
        }
    }
}
```

The file will be opened in excel and all kind of languages are present in the data. The `os.write` parts are for prefixing the file with a byte order mark as to enable all kinds of characters.

Somehow the amount of lines in the file do not match the count in the loop and I can not figure out how. Any help on what I am doing wrong here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not flushing the stream,Refer [oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#flush--) for more info 
which says that

> Flushes this output stream and forces any buffered output bytes to be
>   written out. The general contract of flush is that calling it is an
>   indication that, if any bytes previously written have been buffered by
>   the implementation of the output stream, such bytes should immediately
>   be written to their intended destination. If the intended destination
>   of this stream is an abstraction provided by the underlying operating
>   system, for example a file, then flushing the stream guarantees only
>   that bytes previously written to the stream are passed to the
>   operating system for writing; it does not guarantee that they are
>   actually written to a physical device such as a disk drive.
>
> The flush method of OutputStream does nothing.

You need to flush as well as close the stream. There are 2 ways

1. manually call close() and flush().
2. use try with resource

As I can see from your code that you have already implemented try with resource and also BufferedReader class also implements Closeable, Flushable so use code as per below

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try (OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(FILE); BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))){         
            os.write(239);
            os.write(187);
            os.write(191);

            for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++) {               
                writer.write(Integer.toString(i));
                writer.newLine();               
            }          
        } catch (IOException e) {                       
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println(checkLineCount(COUNT, new File(FILE)));
    }
```

Comment: I have chosen to implement your version as it seems more elegant by using the try-with-resources nicely.

Answer (score 3):

You simply need to flush and close your output stream (forcing fsync) before opening the file for input and counting. Try adding:

```
writer.flush();
writer.close();
```

inside your try-block. after the for-loop in the main method.

Comment: Obviously, if you want to reuse your writer after calling _checkLineCount_, you don't have to close the stream. Invoking _flush()_ is enough to perform fsync.

Answer (score 2):

(As a side note).

Note that using a BOM is optional, and (in many cases) reduces the portability of your files (because not all consuming app's are able to handle it well). It does *not* guarantee that the file has the advertised character encoding. So i would recommend to remove the BOM. When using Excel, just select the file and and choose UTF-8 as encoding.

Answer (score 0):

When `COUNT` is 1, the code in `main()` will write a file with two lines, a line with data plus an empty line afterwards. Then you call `checkLineCount(COUNT, file)` expecting that it will return 1 but it returns 2 because the file has actually two lines.
Therefore if you want the counter to match you must not write a new line after the last line.

Answer (score 0):

(As another side note).

Notice that writing CSV-files the way you are doing is *really* bad practice. CSV is not so easy as it may look at first sight! So, unless you *really* know what you are doing (so being aware of all CSV quirks), use a library!